# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@11.2.14

Tags: angular, npm, ng

Trying to build and run an angular project with the following package.json.

[package.json](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer-admin/blob/main/package.json)

After running `npm i`, seems package get installed with some warnings. No errors.

I am seeing errors, which I dont make sense,  while running `npm ls @angular/core`. ng2-smart-table@1.7.2 is the latest version.

```
za:shopizer-admin za$ npm ls @angular/core
shopizer-admin@ /Users/za/project/shopizer-admin
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@11.2.14 
└─┬ codelyzer@6.0.2
  └── @angular/core@9.0.0 

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^10.0.0, required by ng2-smart-table@1.7.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^10.2.4, required by ng6-file-man@3.0.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0, required by ngx-malihu-scrollbar@9.0.0-beta.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^8.0.0||^9.0.0, required by ngx-summernote@0.7.7
```

Tried changing node version, TS version, cli version, but seeing more issues. I would like to just be able align everything with angular 11.

Comment: Maybe read the documentation that tells you how to install that?  Hint:  It's not what you did.

Comment: @possum i did try with 
npm install --legacy-peer-deps. I also tried building the project inside a dcoekr image. Tried following https://update.angular.io/ but just seeing more issues. I read the document man times. And that is why I am here.

Comment: @possum can you please point me on what I missed, from the doc.